# How do i can modify List<Model> items from razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a RAZOR (ASP.NET MVC 3) and a model of type List.
I want to modify any element from Model into Razor and after to post exactly the same model BUT to be updated with any value MODIFIED (if it was been modified).

```
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr> 
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputID)</td>

            @if (@ViewBag.editFlag)
            {
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.InputName)</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputName)</td>
            }  
        }
```

. I want to be saved for AJAX CALL the same model but modified if it has undergone some changes

And my ajax call:

```
      $("#editButton").click(function () {
       $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Content("~/PhysicalInput/UpdatePhysicalInput")",
                data: { 
                    jsonData: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model));  
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) 
                {
                    if (html.Success) 
                    {
                         window.location.href="ViewList?editFlag=false";
                    }
                    else { }
                },
                error: function(e) {  }
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you have already

Comment: are you wanting to modify the list server side before the HTML is rendered or client side from browser or user action?

Comment: Please explain better/more. Do you want to change from inside Razor? Store it somehow?

Comment: I want to modify the List before it to reach at SERVER SIDE (CONTROLLER)

Answer (score 0):

What you have is just posting the original model back to the server. If you don't have a large model then you need to change the data line to:

```
data: { field1: $('.field1').val(), field2: $('.field2').val(), etc }
```

That will send the current values of those fields back to your action.
Just a note, you can replace your Url.Content with:

```
@Url.Action(Action, Controller)
```

or in your case:

```
@Url.Action("UpdatePhysicalInput", "PhysicalInput")
```

A little cleaner to write and makes it a lot easier to add additional parameters.